# manipulate text edge labels ctree

Tags: r, data-visualization, party

Got a  ctree with four labels, but the categories are long text therefore just the first is shown.

```
category;presence;ratio;tested;located
palindromic_recursion;1;0;0;0
conceptual_comprehension;0;1;0;0
infoxication_syndrome;0;0;1;0
foreign_words_abuse;0;0;0;1
palindromic_recursion;1;0;0;0
conceptual_comprehension;0;1;0;0
infoxication_syndrome;0;0;1;0
foreign_words_abuse;0;0;0;1

concepts.ctree <- ctree(category ~., data)
plot(concepts.ctree)
```

[image: plotted ctree]

is there any way or parameter for manipultating (rotate) text, edge label names and this way force them to be all shown in plot?

My real data is much bigger but this sample is ok to test it if you do not use zoom tool.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

There wasn't an option for this up to now. But I just tweaked the development version of `partykit` on [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=261) to support this feature. Currently, the package is re-building but hopefully you can soon say `install.packages("partykit", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` - or if you don't want to wait that long, simply check out the SVN and re-build yourself.

In the new version, you can pass the `rot` and `just` arguments to `grid.text()` to control rotation and justification of the x-axis labels.

Read the data:

```
data <- read.csv2(textConnection(
"category;presence;ratio;tested;located
palindromic_recursion;1;0;0;0
conceptual_comprehension;0;1;0;0
infoxication_syndrome;0;0;1;0
foreign_words_abuse;0;0;0;1
palindromic_recursion;1;0;0;0
conceptual_comprehension;0;1;0;0
infoxication_syndrome;0;0;1;0
foreign_words_abuse;0;0;0;1"
))
```

Fit the tree (using the `partykit` implementation of `ctree()`):

```
library("partykit")
concepts.ctree <- ctree(category ~ ., data = data)
```

For visualization create a viewport with sufficiently large margins on the x-axis first. Then, add the tree to the existing viewport page and set the rotation/justification arguments for the barplot.

```
pushViewport(plotViewport(margins = c(6, 0, 0, 0)))
plot(concepts.ctree, tp_args = list(rot = 45, just = c("right", "top")),
  newpage = FALSE)
```

[image: ctree with rotated x-axis labels]

Comment: The improved version of `partykit` is now online on R-Forge (https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=261) and can be installed as indicated in the answer.